# Change default sails.id cookie name

Tags: sails.js

I need to hide or change the sails.id cookie name. I do not want anyone to identify that my app runs on sails js because if he/she finds out a bug then could affect my whole system

Any idea of doing this ?

Cheers Guys.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can change the key that is used to identify the session via the `key` property of `sails.config.session`.  So, in **config/session.js**:

```
module.exports = {

  secret: '<your session secret>',
  key: 'some.sessid' // <-- will be used instead of sails.sid

}
```

Comment: FYI in recent versions of Sails, use `name` instead of `key`: https://sailsjs.com/documentation/reference/configuration/sails-config-session

Answer (score 1):

It should be like this,

```
module.exports = {
  secret: '<your session secret>',
  name: 'some.sessid' // <-- will be used instead of sails.sid

}
```

Comment: This is correct in Sails ≥v1
https://sailsjs.com/documentation/reference/configuration/sails-config-session#?the-session-id-cookie